# Analytics pass field value to Sitecore Context for React component

Tags: xdb

I am trying to implement a class that uses the **Sitecore.Analytics.OmniChannel.Pipelines.DetermineInteractionChannel.DetermineChannelProcessorBase** class. My question was to know if there was a way to pass the queried item field's value in a way similar to how it is possible to extend the Layout Service in Sitecore JSS by passing values through the context and make them available to a React component. Something similar to [Extending Sitecore JSS Layout](https://jss.sitecore.com/docs/techniques/extending-layout-service/extending-layout-service-overview) if possible.

The method where I want to implement the logic is the following

```
public override void Process(DetermineChannelProcessorArgs args){
 string sitecoreQuery = "myQuery"
Item myItem = Context.Database.SelectSingleItem("myQuery");
string fieldValue = myItem.fields["myField]?.Value;
//make fieldValue available to get from React component
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This was resolved using Sitecore.Context.HttpContext and then creating a separate extension like the one shown in the link above.

Analytics handler class

```
public override void Process(DetermineChannelProcessorArgs args){
   string sitecoreQuery = "myQuery";
   Item myItem = Context.Database.SelectSingleItem("myQuery");
   string fieldValue = myItem.Fields["myField"]?.Value;
   Sitecore.Context.HttpContext.Session.Add("myField", fieldValue);
}
```

Layout extension class

```
protected override void DoProcess(GetLayoutServiceContext args, AppConfiguration application){
var fieldValue = Sitecore.Context.HttpContext.Session["myField"];
args.ContextData.Add("fieldName", fieldValue);
}
```